# Core Data - Doing a fetch request only retrieves 1 record; when 10 are inserted?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In our system a `user` has many `accountCredits`

These `accountCredits` come from server.

I have a request which retrieves and inserts 10 records in the `mainContext` of a Core Data entity of `accountCredits` and can see that these 10 records in my Xcode console log.  They appear to be successfully inserted.  I can see them in the Xcode console log.

However, straight afterwards I perform a very basic fetch request to retrieve the user and their respective `accountCredits` -- it should see 10; but it only ever see's 1 and I don't know why.

The first thing I did was to check the `context` in every step (before, during, after) and the `context` id does not change.  So its not a context issue.

But I am not sure why its only seeing 1 record, when I know and have logged that 10 records are being inserted.

I've tried to format to make it understandable and paste the code below;

```
NSArray *accountCredits = [resource linkedResourceForKey:@"accountCredits"];
if (accountCredits) {
    for (JSONAPIResource *accountCreditResource in accountCredits) {
        VICAccountCredits *accountCredits = [VICAccountCredits accountCreditFromResource:accountCreditResource inContext:context];
        if (accountCredits) {
            [accountCredits setUser:user];
            NSLog(@"userAPI.accountCredit - %@ %lu %@", accountCredits.code, (long)[accountCredits.amountGBP integerValue], accountCredits.user.name);
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"------");

NSLog(@"... After loading ...");

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"AccountCredits -- %@", [info valueForKey:@"accountCredits"]);
    VICAccountCredits *cr = [info valueForKey:@"accountCredits"];
    NSLog(@"cr - %@ %@", cr.code, cr.user.name);
}
```

The `accountCreditForResource` creates the `accountCredit` like this (edited);

```
+ (VICAccountCredits *)accountCreditFromResource:(JSONAPIResource *)resource inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSString *id = [resource safeObjectForKey:@"id"];
    VICAccountCredits *accountCredit = [VICAccountCredits objectWithRemoteID:id inContext:context];

    if(!accountCredit) {
        accountCredit = [self insertInManagedObjectContext:context];
        accountCredit.remoteID = id;
    }

    accountCredit.amountGBP = [[resource safeObjectForKey:@"amountGBP"] safeObjectForKey:@"amount"];
    accountCredit.code = [[resource safeObjectForKey:@"links"] safeObjectForKey:@"code"];    
    return accountCredit;
}
```

I have used breakpoints inside the `if (!accountCredit)` and see that indeed it does enter the if-statement and does insert it into the correct or `mainContext`.

Log/console reports:

```
Contexts = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7fa86b624270> 
userAPI.accountCredit - G0CR7 1000 a d
userAPI.accountCredit - A1GH5 1000 a d
userAPI.accountCredit - A2EF7 1000 a d
userAPI.accountCredit - A4JX4 1000 a d
userAPI.accountCredit - A6NA9 1000 a d
userAPI.accountCredit - A9DI2 1000 a d
userAPI.accountCredit - D1RK0 1000 a d
userAPI.accountCredit - D2LG1 1000 a d
userAPI.accountCredit - E0UH0 1000 a d
userAPI.accountCredit - E3TU4 1000 a d
------
.. After loading ...

AccountCredits -- <VICAccountCredits: 0x7fa86b63e870> (entity: AccountCredit; id: 0xd000000000100002 <x-coredata://A4310709-6655-4333-8FE3-2C92821DA793/AccountCredit/p4> ; data: {
    amountGBP = 1000;
    code = E3TU4;
    remoteID = 548f137824848be367e1aac3;
    user = "0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://A4310709-6655-4333-8FE3-2C92821DA793/User/p1>";
})
-> 112 cr - E3TU4 a d
```

I find this hard to understand why when inserting 10 records it can only see 1?

Can someone shed light on this?

I did check the `context`... it never changes.

I even tried deleting the app, and restarting/cleaning the simulator of all data.

---

Turns out it was missing the correct relationship in core data.  Thanks  all who helped.

Comment: What is a relationship between a `User` and `AccountCredit `? Does it have an inverse relationship? Also, are you sure that inside `accountCreditFromResource` method you create ten different `AccountCredit` objects, not modify the same object ten times?

Comment: I am looking at Core Data xcdatamodel and it appears its one to one.  I'm not sure how I overlooked this.  I will now see if this solves the problem.

Comment: It appears that I was indeed missing this One to Many relationship; currently I fixed the issue -- but am experiencing some core data faults.  I believe I should be able to resolve it.   I am clearing out the app and resetting the app each time to prevent issues -- hopefully its just a relationship issue

Comment: Yep, it was missing a relationship.  I am just working through the current core data faults but with to thank you @michalciuba for your help.   Not sure why I missed it.

Comment: As for Core Data faults, they are not errors, don't worry about them. They mean that an object has been fetched but its properties have not yet been loaded into memory (lazy-loading, kind of optimization). More about it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html

Comment: Very well.  The issue is resolved now.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
//set properety for array with data

@property (strong) NSMutableArray *data;


NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
    self.data = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

Dont forget to put this method in your view controller:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. Your answer describes how to setup Core Data stack, but the OP has already set it up.

Comment: It appears that I didn't set up one of the relationships correctly; it should have been a one-to-many relationship in Core data -- and for some reason it just wasn't set up.